# Convert Vector From Dataframe

Tags: r, list, vector

I have one vector created using the following code:

```
vectorA<-c(1.125,2.250,3.501)
```

I have another vector stored in a data frame:

```
vectordf<-data.frame()
vectordf[1,1]<-'1.125,2.250,3.501'
vectorB<-vectordf[1,1]
```

I need vectorB to be the same as vectorA so I can use it in another function.  Right now the two vectors are different as shown below:

```
printerA<-paste("vectorA=",vectorA)
printerB<-paste("vectorB=",vectorB)
print(printerA)
print(printerB)

dput(vectorA)
dput(vectorB)

[1] "vectorA= 1.125" "vectorA= 2.25"  "vectorA= 3.501"
[1] "vectorB= 1.125 2.250 3.501"
c(1.125, 2.25, 3.501)
"1.125 2.250 3.501"
```

How can I get vectorB into the same format as vectorA?  I have tried using as.numeric, as.list, as.array, as.matrix.

Comment: `vectorB <- scan(text = '1.125,2.250,3.501', sep = ",")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `scan`.

```
printerB<-paste("vectorB=", scan(text = vectordf[1,1], sep = ','))
```

And now `printerA` and `printerB` are

```
printerA
#[1] "vectorA= 1.125" "vectorA= 2.25"  "vectorA= 3.501"
printerB
#[1] "vectorB= 1.125" "vectorB= 2.25"  "vectorB= 3.501"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you've called "vectorB" isn't quite a vector as you imagine it -- it's a **string** vector of length 1 consisting of numbers separated by commas.

Your idea to use `as.numeric()` is good, but `as.numeric()` doesn't quite know how to parse the string with commas as a vector of distinct numbers. So, you first want to split the string:

```
vectorB <- unlist(strsplit(vectorB, ",", fixed = T))
```

The `strsplit()` call will chop up `vectorB` into different vector sub-parts based on where it finds the commas. The data structure it returns is a list, so we flatten it back down to a vector with `unlist()`. *Then*, your `as.numeric()` idea will work:

```
vectorB <- as.numeric(vectorB)
```

Obviously you can clean that up into a single line if you wish, but I wanted to clearly illustrate where the hole in your strategy was.

---

To make the answer more complete: the reason why this mismatch happened at all was in this line early on in your code:

```
vectordf[1,1]<-'1.125,2.250,3.501'
```

The type of the object on the right side of `<-` is a string vector, and it's a vector of length 1. To fix this, you could have used

```
vectordf[1:3, 1] <- c(1.125, 2.25, 3.501)
```

because the type of the object on the right is now a *numeric* vector of length *3*. Note that we had to adjust the indexing on the left side by changing the row index to be `1:3`.